# WiX: Install to different location depending on build and site location

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Looking for a way out of the corner my company has painted itself into.

Windows Services are currently installed by manually copying files around and running various batch files to install / uninstall. Locations differ by site and depending on whether the installed code is for production or test usage. So my debug build might need to install into

`C:\someFolder\Site1\Test`

while the Release build of the same code would install into

`C:\someFolder\Site1`

Currently only 2 sites but probably expanding soon.

I'm trying to put together a WiX install project (VS2010, WiX 3.5) to handle the installation. I'm not able to change the install folder definition (much as I would like to!) and I'm running into problems trying to understand how I might approach the problem. Being a newbie to WiX doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question about release/debug versions: 
At the place in your code where you are defining your target directory, you can conditionally set it based on the build version. For example, Debug is an available variable that can be used like:

```
         <!-- inside of somefolder/site target definition, conditionally append test dir -->
         <?ifdef var.Debug ?>
           <Directory Id="TestId" Name="test" />
         <?endif?>
```

You can also add other build dependent variables in visual studio for each type of release. This would be a unique build for each target situation model. This could easily get confusing to users about which version they should use.

The other model - one build with flexible target locations:
For the different site directories: Depends on how those sites are created.
 If they exist previous to your install, just use wix's directorysearch to set a property used to build the target directory.
 If instead the target directory is decided at install time, and its based on user's decision, then you'll need to prompt for the name or type (site). This will be similar to the typical situation of asking for a custom install directory. You can modify one of the sample custom wix dialogs included in the wix source that do this and add that dialog to your project's next/back flow.

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought about conditional directories in that way. I agree the end result will start to get messy so I'll try your Othe model, looks much easier to understand.